# Issues with WiFi (seems bus related) under load

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, webcam

I have some interesting issues with a new MBP (13", early 2015, bought early 2016, corporate reseller) which seem to be connected to some internal bus. In all fairness I have not delved into the exact layout of the MBP-mobo to figure out specifics, but it seems like whenever WiFi, webcam or USB come under heavier lasting loads most peripherals needs to be reset (including WiFi).

My minimal working example of the issue is watching twitch.tv with the flash-player (ie flash enabled in safari). This is enough to kill the WiFi within a minute.

I've also gotten the same effect by just using the webcam to record me talking for a couple of minutes, although this does not always happen. Same thing with listening on music with a headset. Regardless of how the "issue" is initiated, only the WiFi shows up in the log, and only the wl0 interface, but most USB-devices need to be physically reconnected for the computer to detect them again.

Examples from the log:

```
28/02/16 23:16:54,000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 3355.995355: wl0: fifo 0: data error
28/02/16 23:16:54,000 kernel[0]: ARPT: 3355.995364: wl0: fatal error, reinitializing, total count of reinit's[9], @'wlc_bmac_fifoerrors':9913
```

Example from log when usb (audio in this case) goes down:

```
29/02/16 09:34:05,000 kernel[0]: WARNING: AppleUSBAudio has detected that a connected USB audio device is sending too much audio data.
29/02/16 09:34:05,000 kernel[0]: WARNING: This USB audio device may not function properly. Please notify the device manufacturer.
```

Example from log when webcam causes usb / wifi / webcam down:

```
28/02/16 23:16:52,290 AppleCameraAssistant[4824]: FrameReceiverMessageCallback: KernelFrameDropNotification (Frames are dropping).  The firmware is not returning buffers quickly enough.
```

Has anyone encountered something similar? Could you fix it somehow?

To clarify, either of these event can cause this "south bridge" shutdown / reset, which reinitiates the WiFi, reinitiates USB-ports and shuts off the webcam.

Additional info:

- This happens regardless of AP.
- It is much harder to reproduce when on ethernet/usb-adapter.
- WiFi + headset + webcam (+ skype) resets "the bus" in under a minute.
- Today it happened on average every 12 minutes.
- corecaptured (the deamon for logging errors) catches it, but only that the wifi driver goes down.

I've tried

- SMC reset multiple times
- NVRAM reset multiple times
- different users
- w/o peripherals
- w/o power cord

If needed I can pastepin a lot of logs.

Adding lsmod / kextstat output as well. How can I verify that I have the correct version?

```
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>
    1   89 0xffffff7f80a42000 0x9c80     0x9c80     com.apple.kpi.bsd (15.3.0) 5E7359BE-8EA6-4E1C-AA25-45280112628D
    2    8 0xffffff7f80db3000 0x3890     0x3890     com.apple.kpi.dsep (15.3.0) 4B6DB3C5-7177-472A-A36A-7A06ACD0E762
    3  113 0xffffff7f80a04000 0x20e20    0x20e20    com.apple.kpi.iokit (15.3.0) DF86E58A-E0D3-4E0A-BB9C-06086D46B1C8
    4  119 0xffffff7f80a25000 0xd000     0xd000     com.apple.kpi.libkern (15.3.0) AA5CEF16-CD25-4C73-8919-C5BFC57D8510
    5  106 0xffffff7f80a00000 0x3d50     0x3d50     com.apple.kpi.mach (15.3.0) 3AC467F0-EBA7-4BAF-BEE3-B96760D5DD10
    6   53 0xffffff7f80a32000 0x96d0     0x96d0     com.apple.kpi.private (15.3.0) 54C14879-1649-4FB2-8208-860FEBD031DE
    7   67 0xffffff7f80a3c000 0x58a0     0x58a0     com.apple.kpi.unsupported (15.3.0) 9E1F8706-C490-4FDA-B7D3-6B8E9FCEBD6C
    8    5 0xffffff7f80dba000 0x95000    0x95000    com.apple.kec.corecrypto (1.0) D6E082B5-93B2-3FF0-AB4B-4AA310173CE8 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
    9    0 0xffffff7f80ef8000 0xd000     0xd000     com.apple.kec.pthread (1) 39D0B4EB-B7F4-3891-96C2-F8B886656C8A <7 6 5 4 1>
   10    1 0xffffff7f80f13000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.kec.Libm (1) 9DDD9196-3824-3DCA-BAAA-7F383BC13C37 <4>
   11   27 0xffffff7f81245000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily (1.4) 5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D <7 6 4 3>
   12   31 0xffffff7f80b2c000 0x30000    0x30000    com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily (2.9) F398CE94-0FBD-3E8E-A7AB-55F7F05A81ED <7 6 5 4 3>
   13    2 0xffffff7f82d18000 0x60000    0x60000    com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform (4.0) 3BE4E926-E063-3BBD-BE05-F6F97358C7A4 <12 11 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   14    1 0xffffff7f811a6000 0xb000     0xb000     com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore (28.30) C31A19C9-8174-3E35-B2CD-3B1B237C0220 <8 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   15    3 0xffffff7f8156f000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily (31) C89107EE-2DF2-3BC3-9F6D-3133D43ED7EF <5 4 3>
   16    7 0xffffff7f80a4c000 0x27000    0x27000    com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily (2.1) DC1AAB7C-F417-3238-BB3F-2A5B84D67B90 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
   17    0 0xffffff7f8165e000 0x19000    0x19000    com.apple.driver.DiskImages (417.2) 97177A33-27BD-34A9-9B42-1173BE480BCD <16 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   18    1 0xffffff7f8262b000 0x1e000    0x1e000    com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager (1.0) E3817462-FFEE-38AE-839B-79932133E7EF <8 7 5 4 3 1>
   19    2 0xffffff7f80eb9000 0x12000    0x12000    com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity (1.0.5) 09620E73-2D73-3F62-9E5D-4B9DC2147F70 <8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1>
   20    0 0xffffff7f82649000 0x28000    0x28000    com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore (2) 7AF14D78-EEBE-3474-B605-66CC957F2FE5 <19 18 8 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   21    0 0xffffff7f80db7000 0x2000     0x2000     com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet (8) 7F6B05B1-14AC-3634-B5CA-7F69452730B4 <7 6 5 4 2 1>
   22    2 0xffffff7f80ecb000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.kext.AppleMatch (1.0.0d1) F2211BA2-E656-3187-B06E-CF9D6A3A3B5A <4 1>
   23    1 0xffffff7f80ed0000 0x1e000    0x1e000    com.apple.security.sandbox (300.0) F3202072-6ED5-33BF-97B0-AD49F500ABF6 <22 19 16 7 6 5 4 3 2 1>
   24    0 0xffffff7f80eee000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.security.quarantine (3) FEC5D575-4604-37D6-B550-83B7D17E3E76 <23 22 7 6 5 4 2 1>
   25    0 0xffffff7f82d8f000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall (163) 113F310F-1904-3F41-A206-1D275BF7A397 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
   26    0 0xffffff7f82ce6000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC (1.7) 46368557-CAF1-3FAC-AF62-A03389987023 <4 3>
   27    3 0xffffff7f814fb000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily (1.1) EA577FC5-B1EE-38B4-9B62-2938C01C2CB2 <5 4 3>
   28    0 0xffffff7f82d7e000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC (4.0) 696533F4-4E49-3C00-86D7-47B7F5FB87D8 <27 13 11 5 4 3>
   29    0 0xffffff7f8253e000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS (2.1) 558EB25D-8E3F-3429-B2DC-ADAE2EF0F7C3 <7 4 3>
   30    0 0xffffff7f82913000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleHPET (1.8) 801E20D9-1D7A-353F-A638-05430128D61D <11 7 5 4 3>
   31    1 0xffffff7f8296d000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime (2.0) CFC72657-568A-33B3-B84A-CF659674E655 <7 6 5 4 3>
   32    1 0xffffff7f82972000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM (2.0) DFA558FE-59F9-32AA-8C3A-82BD65ECC094 <31 7 6 5 4 3 2 1>
   33    7 0xffffff7f811b1000 0x76000    0x76000    com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily (2.0.0) 12BE7C40-B94D-363E-8F4F-8E471F66FB92 <14 7 6 5 4 3 2 1>
   34    0 0xffffff7f82d88000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons (4.0) 767834A6-B80F-36ED-9C0A-A6179A144279 <33 13 11 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   35    0 0xffffff7f8256c000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.AppleRTC (2.0) 6409E881-1F83-380E-8F03-F21DCFC4BF53 <11 5 4 3 1>
   36    0 0xffffff7f82544000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager (161.0.0) DD5F1FAE-434C-3D51-955A-30FD426E43E9 <27 11 5 4 3 1>
   37    3 0xffffff7f8103e000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties (1.0.1) D338A98F-2B8F-3411-BD87-BD00F620A223 <4 3 1>
   38   14 0xffffff7f81042000 0x69000    0x69000    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily (1.0.1) 5FF3F801-2AB5-38D2-93C2-51E00427D8FA <37 7 5 4 3 1>
   39    1 0xffffff7f810e8000 0x98000    0x98000    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily (900.4.1) 785E8408-1158-32CE-BF1F-9DA7804BDE5B <38 12 7 5 4 3 1>
   40    1 0xffffff7f8267c000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac (2.0.59) 064EEF27-D143-34A6-8F53-BAAF0A151DF8 <12 11 5 4 3>
   41    1 0xffffff7f8124e000 0x3f000    0x3f000    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI (1.0.1) 38F68C79-811D-3AA2-B8D4-0D444FF4DB4B <38 11 7 5 4 3 1>
   42    0 0xffffff7f81293000 0x20000    0x20000    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI (1.0.1) 7AC984CE-8AAA-3B8D-92E3-24BE18DF3DEC <41 38 12 11 7 5 4 3 1>
   43    1 0xffffff7f8269b000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi (2.0.59) 5D1C6CC8-9376-39B5-A291-7B7C5D2EDEFB <12 11 7 5 4 3>
   45    1 0xffffff7f826a5000 0x14000    0x14000    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController (2.0.59) 601A2F9B-1F16-325C-A6F3-9638DE5FB095 <43 40 11 5 4 3>
   46    1 0xffffff7f828e6000 0x17000    0x17000    com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport (41.7) 8EFDF648-A75E-3089-9DEE-ED9BB9435978 <45 11 5 4 3 1>
   47    3 0xffffff7f818b4000 0x22000    0x22000    com.apple.driver.corecapture (1.0.4) B80FBC9C-24F9-3399-B347-01816E4EDD46 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
   48    6 0xffffff7f80ffe000 0x2d000    0x2d000    com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily (3.2) 35F05D83-F2EC-3047-8422-E65BAF0144B2 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
   49    1 0xffffff7f818de000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient (1.0.1b8) DC173C97-9F4D-39D5-8814-68B0BAD27370 <48 4 3 1>
   50    1 0xffffff7f818e6000 0xd4000    0xd4000    com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family (1110.26) A7F70957-7DBC-39ED-ACA7-3A7BA653D115 <48 47 8 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   51    0 0xffffff7f819c3000 0x6bf000   0x6bf000   com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360 (1020.17.1a1) 1D44A63A-83A8-335C-BBF5-629657661B93 <50 49 48 47 12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   52    5 0xffffff7f813ea000 0xe0000    0xe0000    com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily (5.1.0) 6D71D503-3CBC-3D14-961B-2DABB69F7DD1 <5 4 3 1>
   53    0 0xffffff7f82446000 0x1b000    0x1b000    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI (4.0.4) E3CA1A84-50CA-342F-8B32-C7CFA8D13E11 <52 12 11 5 4 3 1>
   54    0 0xffffff7f82900000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver (41.7) 162085CF-EB52-38D5-AA5F-64CD63FAF9A9 <46 33 5 4 3 1>
   55    1 0xffffff7f82388000 0x18000    0x18000    com.apple.driver.AppleHIDTransport (5) 4F6504CC-C655-324D-A16C-C4683DC41CBB <33 5 4 3 1>
   56    1 0xffffff7f823a5000 0x2e000    0x2e000    com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver (304.10) 7536E774-8C5F-3DD7-A326-48597EF0368E <55 33 15 7 5 4 3 1>
   57    0 0xffffff7f823e8000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver (86) BF37BB87-92B1-3102-AE2A-607D5BA39C8B <56 33 6 5 4 3 1>
   58    0 0xffffff7f823db000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard (181) E4D6A0C3-5C8D-3652-B673-3FAFAA027E2E <33 4 3>
   59    0 0xffffff7f82434000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter (2.0.2) 6347338C-0AAD-3877-9C4E-E7C3DBF054DF <52 12 5 4 3 1>
   60    1 0xffffff7f82483000 0x10000    0x10000    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily (4.1.3) F046449A-81B0-306B-82BA-13E65A1349B1 <52 11 5 4 3 1>
   61    0 0xffffff7f824b0000 0x6000     0x6000     com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter (4.1.3) 6516419E-BD78-3A7C-8505-BA37CFEE7FCE <60 52 5 4 3 1>
   62    2 0xffffff7f81860000 0x1b000    0x1b000    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily (2.8.1) 58B77CC0-5211-342E-8935-8D05E0B96867 <5 4 3 1>
   63    0 0xffffff7f82ceb000 0x1e000    0x1e000    com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort (3.1.8) 20356FAA-8898-36F8-BAAD-8961AFC23E9B <62 12 5 4 3 1>
   64    0 0xffffff7f8188b000 0x1c000    0x1c000    com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage (2.8.5) 0A852267-0F62-363B-86D7-C2B02972EE48 <62 16 6 5 4 3 1>
   67    0 0xffffff7f82204000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.BootCache (38) C1EA21DC-CEC4-34EF-8172-8D217927D3EC <7 6 5 4 3 1>
   68    0 0xffffff7f82c08000 0x6000     0x6000     com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib (1.0.0) 8A37264E-9D9A-3B95-B0A1-EB1947CF70DA <6 4 3 2 1>
   69    0 0xffffff7f82c10000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless (1.0.0d1) 8A48FC7E-CD9D-39E4-A243-59BBEB5D65BE <7 6 4 3 2 1>
   71    0 0xffffff7f82102000 0xdb000    0xdb000    com.apple.driver.CoreStorage (517.20.1) 91927E0E-0674-3682-8CA1-6AC338C4FBC7 <16 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   74    1 0xffffff7f81382000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice (1.0.1) 3E1A0840-033C-321B-B5ED-7BEA6996B1E0 <38 5 4 3 1>
   75    0 0xffffff7f8123b000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice (1.0.1) 65F7A241-C50F-3370-9CE8-54566F0130DE <38 33 5 4 3 1>
   76    1 0xffffff7f8231c000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.usb.networking (5.0.0) B67E6F42-8948-3E27-9935-FD8CE6E3310E <38 5 4 3 1>
   77    0 0xffffff7f82351000 0x18000    0x18000    com.apple.driver.usb.ethernet.asix (5.0.0) E7AE9880-3970-38D8-9953-362C315DE32A <76 74 48 38 5 4 3 1>
   78    3 0xffffff7f80ae9000 0x2b000    0x2b000    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily (3.7.7) 49F2C1F9-18D8-3D7C-B3DA-B7716B41B0BF <6 5 4 3 1>
   79    1 0xffffff7f810b4000 0x2d000    0x2d000    com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver (1.0.0) B9DE23AE-01F9-3985-927E-57555C1C503D <78 38 16 6 5 4 3 1>
   80    1 0xffffff7f80f1c000 0x18000    0x18000    com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice (3.7.7) A3F040D5-CB27-3C8D-AFC1-1034C770E5BF <78 16 6 5 4 3 1>
   81    0 0xffffff7f82512000 0xb000     0xb000     com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader (3.7.1) 4AC15D28-BE78-3324-8A4A-9BD5F3A4E739 <80 79 78 38 16 5 4 3 1>
   85   15 0xffffff7f81607000 0x3b000    0x3b000    com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily (2.4.1) 429C688E-8DDA-3D15-9C6E-6F3F4855C424 <12 7 5 4 3 1>
   86    1 0xffffff7f825d8000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController (1.0.14d1) 04C9295B-23E8-388B-8BB6-07CC377CADD2 <27 12 11 5 4 3>
   87    6 0xffffff7f81580000 0x19000    0x19000    com.apple.driver.AppleSMC (3.1.9) 535447F9-30E0-39BA-A2B8-1A027DED5D53 <11 7 5 4 3 1>
   88    0 0xffffff7f825e9000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl (1.2.13) FE49EB19-A41C-3E7B-89CE-5411C85593D4 <87 86 85 12 11 7 5 4 3 1>
   89    2 0xffffff7f8221b000 0x7c000    0x7c000    com.apple.vecLib.kext (1.2.0) E62681B7-BE2F-3F89-8065-91C5C2876EBA <10 6 5 4 3>
   90    5 0xffffff7f82297000 0x31000    0x31000    com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily (204.3) 79080C52-FC35-31BA-8C06-087B308D33D1 <89 5 4 3 1>
   91    2 0xffffff7f8292a000 0xc000     0xc000     com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily (272.51.3) 3BF83381-C3DA-3EC4-BBE6-F2024D3EACC7 <5 4 3 1>
   92    1 0xffffff7f8293d000 0x1d000    0x1d000    com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController (272.51.3) AC7816C9-DEF7-310A-B059-5852BF07A843 <91 90 85 12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   93    2 0xffffff7f82716000 0x6c000    0x6c000    com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 (205.1) 9B36322F-2685-3BDD-9734-9BCC39A0AF94 <85 12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   94    3 0xffffff7f82790000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl (3.12.6) F211EB28-182A-34BB-A610-87667618F925 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
   95    0 0xffffff7f82797000 0x56000    0x56000    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer (10.1.2) 43A28CBD-5DDC-3E44-B0A0-4312DBFBA30C <94 93 85 15 12 11 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   97    0 0xffffff7f82c1d000 0xa8000    0xa8000    com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface (5.41.0) 04C26091-6B74-3350-9678-1DABDDCB1099 <12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
   98    1 0xffffff7f8150a000 0xe000     0xe000     com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily (11) 7B499619-A9F2-3CEF-81FA-81DF3A740B19 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
  100    1 0xffffff7f814ff000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily (1.0.0) 514292C4-55BD-3550-9DEB-1431BC04A629 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
  101    0 0xffffff7f82678000 0x2000     0x2000     com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking (4.0.0) A5A73220-5E26-3283-B29B-FEA298629620 <100 4 3>
  102    4 0xffffff7f81576000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily (6.0.0d7) EC53D03F-6CD9-383A-8160-33E02C141EAA <11 7 6 5 4 3>
  103    1 0xffffff7f8159b000 0x17000    0x17000    com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin (1.0.0) 8FA4E640-14CB-364C-9F68-B14F12A714A5 <102 87 39 38 11 7 6 5 4 3 1>
  108    4 0xffffff7f8164e000 0x10000    0x10000    com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport (2.4.1) ED747668-8718-3FB4-A4F4-2AC731D5B16F <85 12 7 5 4 3>
  109    1 0xffffff7f82bdb000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert (1.1.0) 70C85E35-16FC-3B76-A3B1-18625732013B <108 87 85 12 5 4 3>
  110    0 0xffffff7f82cde000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight (170.8.8) 8A0C0765-B999-38D3-9B32-74AC41B59A2D <109 108 85 12 5 4 3>
  111    2 0xffffff7f81705000 0xbd000    0xbd000    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily (4.4.3f4) 022A55C7-EF37-3BE7-AC09-0436CDEFCE95 <15 7 5 4 3 1>
  112    1 0xffffff7f817d5000 0x2a000    0x2a000    com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport (4.4.3f4) 67B0326E-F86A-3AEF-BE41-99958414F094 <111 38 12 11 7 5 4 3 1>
  113    0 0xffffff7f817ff000 0xb000     0xb000     com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport (4.4.3f4) FDF51F5F-927E-3A01-9987-9029AD2D3AC4 <112 111 38 12 11 7 5 4 3>
  114    0 0xffffff7f80c07000 0x4000     0x4000     com.intel.driver.EnergyDriver (2.0) 6EC99BBD-0CA2-3CA6-B252-DE46782936C3 <7 5 4 3>
  115    0 0xffffff7f82533000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU (208) 12A49CE9-B8C6-3D99-8F64-74360C5194CE <87 85 5 4 3>
  116    0 0xffffff7f82623000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleLPC (3.1) 32BDCF9F-0473-32D4-9DAE-F523EFB2D244 <102 12 5 4 3>
  118    0 0xffffff7f82466000 0x13000    0x13000    com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP (3.0.8) 65B3F691-0870-3223-BDED-58CD809694AF <52 48 12 5 4 3 1>
  119    1 0xffffff7f82bd8000 0x3000     0x3000     com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl (3.12.6) 1654475C-9A4B-386C-AFA8-0A530194A2F9 <85 12 11 7 5 4 3 1>
  121    1 0xffffff7f814e6000 0x13000    0x13000    com.apple.iokit.IOSurface (108.0.1) 5D984125-CEC9-39B6-BA6E-6C6C6004552C <7 5 4 3 1>
  122    0 0xffffff7f8280c000 0x8b000    0x8b000    com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics (10.1.2) 72DDE1BC-DEE6-3C50-9B45-4B370242EB9A <121 93 85 12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
  123    0 0xffffff7f828d6000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.driver.AppleHV (1) 8E08FFC5-4E33-3D66-BB9B-2EC170B650E6 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
  124    0 0xffffff7f821fd000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder (1) 5A1207B1-02BD-3EAE-B54B-77F361EAF1E7 <47 7 6 5 4 3 1>
  125    0 0xffffff7f820fc000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X (7.0.0) 3164D09B-101E-38E5-9399-BDE428C1E877 <87 7 4 3 1>
  126    0 0xffffff7f816f1000 0xa000     0xa000     com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager (4.4.3f4) A6A7E1A3-4063-3C42-9984-67E3BB1A0191 <98 7 5 4 3 1>
  127    0 0xffffff7f81032000 0x6000     0x6000     com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet (1.0.1) 6D2530ED-C0BC-3F64-B2FC-4490CC30BC06 <48 6 5 4 3 1>
  128    0 0xffffff7f80f05000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry (1) C3F2C16A-A407-389C-AD2B-B8582742FE5E <7 6 5 4 3>
  129    1 0xffffff7f8295a000 0x13000    0x13000    com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib (525) EB6D6178-3438-335D-AF34-296AB6D9E9F7 <5 4>
  130    1 0xffffff7f8297c000 0x131000   0x131000   com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib (272.51.3) F1E07A68-221D-3ED3-A2BA-1735E0582F3F <129 90 89 32 6 5 4 3 1>
  131    0 0xffffff7f82ab7000 0xb2000    0xb2000    com.apple.driver.AppleHDA (272.51.3) 344D4A99-D22C-3E43-9699-82C1B7044CE2 <130 108 92 91 90 85 6 5 4 3 1>
  133    0 0xffffff7f8237f000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient (3.6.1) 6E57BC33-C4AF-3611-97B7-31CA2A2C88DD <85 12 11 7 5 4 3 1>
  134    0 0xffffff7f82bfc000 0x8000     0x8000     com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy (3.7.7) 8EA77EA5-107F-348D-A761-A291D667920E <119 94 85 12 11 7 6 5 4 3 1>
  135    0 0xffffff7f825cb000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog (1) 0CE80268-ACDD-3FCC-8370-8A041468F898 <12 7 6 5 4 3 1>
  136    1 0xffffff7f815b2000 0x7000     0x7000     com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim (1.0.0) B2191973-68F2-3E56-BC52-9A1C0F9A6FA7 <103 102 87 7 4 3>
  137    0 0xffffff7f82bbb000 0x14000    0x14000    com.apple.driver.AGPM (110.20.22) BA5158E0-87CC-3703-8F3F-228264BD7EDA <108 102 94 85 12 6 5 4 3>
  138    0 0xffffff7f825c4000 0x4000     0x4000     com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler (2.6.0d0) C8CADD76-7546-3CCA-86F3-F5EE0B3A11F4 <7 5 4 3>
  139    0 0xffffff7f822d0000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC (1.70) D9EF7435-0F3C-37BD-AA34-F1B7353C8D4F <90 85 12 11 7 5 4 3 1>
  140    1 0xffffff7f80e4f000 0x5000     0x5000     com.apple.kext.triggers (1.0) 5A796890-4ED5-3BA9-8638-84EBBBDD2D53 <7 6 5 4 3 1>
  141    0 0xffffff7f82210000 0x9000     0x9000     com.apple.filesystems.autofs (3.0) 2461725B-E5F1-3947-8AD8-8781308FA614 <140 7 6 5 4 3 1>
  142    0 0xffffff7f82d99000 0x15000    0x15000    com.microsoft.kext.scep_kac (4.5.18) D28CC4B9-4A69-E38F-73EF-9A4915474904 <5 4 3 1>
  143    0 0xffffff7f8134e000 0x2d000    0x2d000    com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub (1.0.1) 271D9C2E-FF74-3503-958E-24C554595575 <38 37 11 5 4 3 1>
  144    0 0xffffff7f82dae000 0x54000    0x54000    com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio (302.15) CC18E05E-1D4F-33F2-83E6-F7B95A3011BD <90 38 37 12 5 4 3 1>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here.  Is your Wifi dying or is it your USB?

Comment: @Allan Something internal seems to be restarting, if it was a "normal PC" I'd say it was an issue with the south bridge, either physical or firmware, which makes it restart every now and then. I do not now if MacBooks use the common north / south bridge setup. I'll update the question if it's unclear.

Comment: @Allan The south bridge normally is in charge of IO, ie wifi, usb and everything connected to external anything.

Comment: A Mac is a "normal PC." If you want to rule out the OS and verify that it is a H/W issue, install Win7 or Win10 on a Boot Camp partition and do what you were doing that initially caused the problem.

Comment: @Allan So there is no way to have a closer look at firmware / drivers / etc? I was googling a bit but found no relevant resources when it comes to Mac firmware.

Comment: What specifically would you like to see on the Mac that you can on a PC?  Your peripherals on the PCIe bus work the exact same way they do on a PC.  As far as WiFi goes, the issues are well documented:  [MBP Wifi Search Results][1]


  [1]: http://www.bing.com/search?q=macbook%20pro%20wifi%20issues&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=macbook%20pro%20wifi%20issues&sc=5-23&sp=-1&sk=&ghc=1&cvid=67BE9AEA047F4975AB8CD22E47FB1309

Comment: @Allan See the kextstat / lsmod output, how exactly do I verify that I have the correct drivers?

Comment: Because they came with OS X and you are on a MBP; as such they are the ONLY drivers available.  Apple is the only company you are going to get drivers from that work with OS X and you can't get individual drivers from them.

Comment: @Allan So there is no way at all to verify integrity of drivers? With regards to issues like http://mjtsai.com/blog/2016/02/28/apple-blacklists-own-ethernet-driver/ that seems really smart :) Ty for your help though :)

Comment: Nope.  My iMac suffers with some WiFi issues, but I fixed it by running a CAT5e cable through the wall that went to my switch/router.  My g/f's 2009 MBP has wifi issues as well - it will just drop connectivity.  She went for the cable solution, too.  Since our Macs are bound to our desks it's not much of an issue for us, but her daughter's MBA (when it's not being repaired for liquid damage) seems to work fine.  It's an OS X issue

Comment: Exactly the same problem. If I run battle.net app, which is downloading stuff with P2P, I get disconnected.. after 3 re-connects within 20 seconds, it is always disabled and I cannot turn it on - I must restart the MBP. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Mejmo Added an answer. Follow my link to the other question by me and see if your symptoms are the same.

Comment: Today I was given a new Macbook from apple.

Comment: Could Apple support provide you a solution?
I'm experiencing exactly the same isse on my MBP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be problems with "overheating", so I installed [Macs Fan Control](http://www.crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control) and set it a bit aggresive, ie linear, and it "solved" it.

I haven't heard back from the support yet though, but there seems to be an issue with the coolant paste to the north bridge. I'll see when I actually have time to turn it in. It goes from ca `40C` to `95C` in mere seconds when the fans are off.

The reason for "overheating" (ie quotation marks) is that it was not under heavy load, but the "CPU System Agent Core"-sensor was showing high values. See this question, [CPU System agent core (TC0E/TC0F) running very high](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234892/cpu-system-agent-core-tc0e-tc0f-running-very-high), where I in detail go through my temps and sensor data.